# How to change password of hotspot in Ubuntu gnome 17.04?

Tags: gnome, 17.04, hot-spot

There are no options like "Edit Connections" as suggested by many other questions.Does anybody know how to change password?

[image][image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `nm-connection-editor` as told by @pomsky