# How to change AP-WIFI key

Tags: internet, 18.04

Recently I installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and when I activate the Wireless Access Point I can not change the key. It is the same every time.

Someone can help me?

Comment: You can use the `nm-connection-editor` Source: https://askubuntu.com/questions/953325/how-to-change-password-of-hotspot-in-ubuntu-gnome-17-04